# Github: Unable to add files to commit

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I am unable to add the files to the staging area. Whenever I try to do this, I get a bunch of errors. Please have a look at the following figure and kindly tell me what's the problem here and how may I solve this? I have searched alot but wasn't able to find the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're running into the windows long path issue?  Take a look at this question and answers: [msys git and long paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992577/msys-git-and-long-paths)